# How many timers in a window?

Tags: javascript, html, web

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how many javascript setTimeout/ setInterval call can be set simultaneously in one page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2553138/how-many-javascript-settimeout-setinterval-call-can-be-set-simultaneously-in-one)

Is there a hard limit on the number of timers in a web window?  In other words, how many concurrent outstanding `setInterval` can I have in one xHTML browser window?

Comment: I think it mostly depends on how frequent the timers run. Always use as few as possible.

Comment: thanks for pointing me to a duplicate!