# NodeJS - Multiple Timeouts vs one Interval for sessions in bots

Tags: javascript, node.js, session, facebook-messenger-bot

I would like the messenger bot to notify the user that their session ended if they did not write/give input to the bot for some time. In order to do so, I first thought about using `setTimeout()` for each user which will reset upon activity. But that means if there will be 100 active users, there will be 100 `Timeouts` at the same time.

I wanted to know, if having one `Interval` instead that checks through each user`s session end timestamp every 30-60 seconds a better approach? The active users are stored in memory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`setTimeout` is more precise in your case: each session will be ended independently and closer to the time it was supposed to end. It will also spread the activity more evenly. Since JS is single-threaded, the timeouts will not fire in parallel, even though there will be hundreds of them at the same time.

`setInterval` will create spikes of activity every 30-60 seconds, and will sometimes let the sessions stay alive longer than they should.

As per the cost of multiple timeouts running at the same time, please see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40948712/4378400).

Comment: Thanks for the test results, it does seem that `Timeouts` are not that heavy as I thought. In terms of session time accuracy, it's not a big deal if they are off by 1 min, since sessions will be at minimum 30 mins long.